# OTEL with IBM MQ JMS ISSUE

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, datadog, otel

We have a backend application with technologies springboot, IBM MQ, Datadog for logging/tracing. The app has a functionality where it is publishing XML message to  a IBM MQ channel. Recently our team has removed datadog and added OTEL for tracing/logging and after making this change the messages published to IBM MQ are getting published with some special extra character in the XML message near the header.

[image]

Comment: Are the extra characters restricted to the logs/trace, or are they also showing up in the messages? You should share the code / settings that you are using for logging.

Comment: @chughts There is no problem in logs/trace. Issue is the MQ messages that are being published with special characters. We want to TURN OFF trace propagation to mq. How can I turn off otel propogation/traceparent to the jms queue?